# Good diff tools under Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: diff, ubuntu-10.04

Could somebody give me some recommendations on diff tools on Ubuntu? Actually what I need is not just file comparison, but also directory comparison.

I think diff tools under Windows is really most convenient, especially WinMerge.

But under Ubuntu, what I can get with high efficiency is only TkDiff, but it only support file comparison?

Hope to get some help from here.

Answer (score 71):

[Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) is an actively-developed, open-source [GUI-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Meld_file1.png) diff utility targeted at developers.

- It is free
- It runs on Linux
- GNU License
- 40+ posts tagged as [meld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meld) on Stack Overflow.
- [Actively developed](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/buglist.cgi?query=product:meld) through February 2013 (the time of this posting)
- Allows two and three way comparison between files and folders
- Supports Subversion, Git, and Mercurial

Comment: But can it open two 40M files? Nope.

Comment: Also, altho it has a pretty face, I find that it's not too bright sometimes (Just Plain Wrong), in ways that I have never seen with WinMerge.

Comment: very easy to install goto `update softwar center` then search `meld`, then install

Comment: It doesn't support automatic merge, as kdiff3 does. Stopper for me.

Answer (score 10):

I usually use `kdiff3` and happy with it. It can handle directories too.

Comment: `meld` has one advantage over `kdiff3` which I learned just today. `meld` is capable of operating with process substitution-style input:
`meld <(ls this) <(ls that)`, while `kdiff3` not so much.

Comment: Wojciech your answer would actually be a right answer. Process substitution is invaluable for comparisons between ssh files and other less obvious diffs.

Comment: `kdiff3` resolves most conflicts automatically, `meld` can't do that.

Answer (score 5):

It's not free software, but [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php) is now available for Linux. I haven't used the Linux version but found BC2 invaluable for merging and comparing files and directories on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the Krusader::Synchronize Directories (Ctrl+Y) tool for this task.

It compares directories and selects a newer files to rewrite the older ones automatically, then you can check the list of the differences and compare the files content (kdiff, kompare or xxdiff) while necessary.
Finally you can start the synchronize action (copying files) itself.

It is crucial for this tool to have a file timestamps (modification time) set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Although not opensource, `p4merge` is free and available on Linux, Windows and Mac. If you are used to Perforce, it will also feel familiar.

My personal taste is `kdiff3` but `p4merge` worth to be mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

While I find `kdiff3` utmostly confusing every time, for simple tasks I like the `dirdiff` utility (see [its manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/dirdiff.1.html)). It is a graphical tool, and while not strong in features for merging, it lets you get a quick overview of relevant differences (hide non-relevant by doing "File -> Hide selection").